# font-style and text-decoration proerties in css

Tags: css

I want to know what is the difference between Css font-style and text-decoration properties.

Can I use `font-style:italic;` or `text-decoration:italic;`? Which one is correct and what is the difference?

Comment: Why don’t you go read up on this yourself, instead of asking us?
 Please make a _reasonable effort_ before you ask a question here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Comment: `italic`  is not valid value for `text-decoration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-decoration: italic` is invalid markup.
Underneath you find valid values for both `text-decoration` and `font-style`.

`text-decoration` can have the following values:

- `none`
- `underline`
- `line-through`
- `overline`

Where `font-style` can have:

- `normal`
- `italic`
- `oblique`

Demo of the styles:

```html
<p style="text-decoration: none">This is a text (text-decoration: none)</p>
<p style="text-decoration: underline">This is a text (text-decoration: underline)</p>
<p style="text-decoration: line-through">This is a text (text-decoration: line-through)</p>
<p style="text-decoration: overline">This is a text (text-decoration: overline)</p>

<p style="font-style: normal">This is a text (font-style: normal)</p>
<p style="font-style: italic">This is a text (font-style: italic)</p>
<p style="font-style: oblique">This is a text (font-style: oblique)</p>
```

Comment: You have not listed all the possible values for each CSS property. Though the answer is only **`text-decoration: italic` is invalid markup**

Comment: I disagree. It will not only solve the OPs problem, but provides additional information as well.  Extra information in this situation doesn't hurt anyone.

Comment: Agree. But Additional information should be complete. It should not mis-leading.

Comment: Fair enough, I changed the order in my answer :)